# Laravel 4: loading Service Provider at runtime

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4

On first thought, this may seem unnecessary, as we have defined `providers` in `config/app.php` to autoload any `ServiceProvider`, but it turns out there is a scenario where they will NOT be autoloaded:

When we run a job from Laravel `Queue` - it would seem my `ServiceProvider` in config are ignore completely, so DI failed with `target ... is not instantiable`.

Register my service providers at runtime in the job does work. e.g.

```
App::register('MyServiceProvider');
```

Is there a reason that Laravel did not autoload my ServiceProvider in such case?

PS: I opened an issue [on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2571) as well, as I am not if this is by design.

Comment: I haven't come across this and it may be a bug but just to tick off the obvious pitfall - are you defining the service providers in your route config or the config for a specific environment - I got burned a couple of times by defining environments by url (which is obviously not picked up from the command line), so if your app config is in a url defined environment that would explain it.

Comment: @WebweaverD - oh man, you are right, even though I did realize it could be issue, I haven't looked closely enough. Any tips on how to define environment that does not depend on url?

Comment: I have submitted an answer with some more info - let me know how you're hosting/running your dev site if you're still having trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your environments by URL, those environments will not be automatically recognised from the command line - I've run into this issue myself when trying to run migrations/seeds.

You can define environments in any way you like since the environment definition accepts a closure but 'out of the box' you can return a regex that matches wither a machine name or a url. examples here - [environment config](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).

One solution  would be to  define your service providers in the app.php at the route of your config (this is the default config and will be used if no other environments are recognised from the command line) OR if you need different settings for different environments you could try defining your environments by machine name - this is the hostname of your machine - on a unix box you can see what this is with echo $HOSTNAME on the command line.

**Another solution from OP**

As the OP has discovered, artisan accepts --env flag on just about every command which allows you to force an environment, so you can call php artisan queue:work --env=local to force it to use the local config when working queues.

Hope this helps

Comment: actually i think `artisan` accepts `--env` flag on just about every commands, so I can still `php artisan queue:work --env=local` to make it use my local config. if you can add that in i will accept this answer.

Comment: I didnt realise you could do that, thanks for the info. I have updated my answer to make it more comprehensive